# AWS Data Pipeline. EC2Resource not able to access redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-iam, amazon-data-pipeline

I am using AWS Data Pipeline to execute SQL queries on redshift which may involve(creating/deleting tables) for the first time. 
Created a SQL Activity which "Runs On" an EC2 instance created as part of data pipeline and a Redshift with Database node with appropriate credentials.

But while running the pipeline , EC2 could not access the redshift database. Error thrown is as follows:

> `Unable to establish connection to jdbc:postgresql://xxxxx/yyyy Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.`

[image: Pipeline]

Probably that it may be because of "ResourceRole" parameter of EC2 which is set to **DataPipelineDefaultResource** and IAM role may not have the right permissions to access the Redshift DB.

What is the right IAM role if that is the root cause for this or there could be some other reason.

Comment: How did you solve this? I'm right now stuck at this particular error.

Comment: Using SQLActivity node instead of EC2Resource where you can give the SQL query directly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect to the cluster using a normal client? If you can't, then it's likely there's no ingress allowed on the Redshift cluster. Maybe [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-refusal-failure-issues.html) might help